# Scheduled messages without setInterval()

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to schedule some things like sending messages with my discord bot.
E.g.: I want the bot to send "Good Morning" every day at 8 am or announce some things.

My problem is: I can't use something like `setInterval()` to execute every 24 hours because if the bot goes offline or has to be restarted it would reset or delay the interval.

Question: How do I execute something at a specific point in time without having to worry about the bot sometimes being offline?

Comment: Hi, I've removed "discord bot" from the title since it's said by both the [tag:discord.js] tag and the first line of the question; this way we can keep questions' titles clean :)

Comment: @FedericoGrandi ok sorry lol :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`cron`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) package: you schedule a job that runs every day at a specific hour (time will be read on the system clock, you'll have to figure it out by yourself for timezones).

Here's an example of a message being sent every day at 8:00 am.

```js
const cron = require('cron');

const channel; // Let's say this is the channel where you want to send it.
const job = new cron.CronJob('0 0 8 * * *', () => {
  channel.send("It's 8:00 am.");
});
```

About the `0 0 8 * * *` pattern: its format is `second minute hour month-day month week-day`.
You can find more about cron patterns [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron#available-cron-patterns).