# How to automate topic posting and to clear the chat before hand

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to use discord.js to post a topic at 3 different intervals: every day, every week and every month.
I will have a different file with the topics for each day. I also want each chat room for the separate topics to clear before posting the new topic.

I am using the code below to automate the interval at which it posts but I need the clear function and also maybe a more streamlined way to post it, or a way to post at a specific time.

```js
bot.on('message', function(message) {
  // Now, you can use the message variable inside
  if (message.content === "$Next") {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      // use the message's channel (TextChannel) to send a new message
      message.channel.send("Test Topic")
        .catch(console.error); // add error handling here
    }, 1 * 10);
  }
});
```

I need to automate these functions and to clear the chat before it posts the new topic. My current code works for automatically posting at the given interval. I need help clearing the channels chat and automatically posting a topic from a saved file.

Comment: Please, share what you are coding, and then we can help. The code you shared solves only like 2% of your problems.

Comment: DO NOT EVER POST YOUR BOT'S TOKEN: by doing that you're allowing anyone to access it! Please delete the comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scheduled messages without setInterval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56027698/scheduled-messages-without-setinterval)

Comment: I just need help with code. How can I get it to automatically post a topic on specific times and dates. And is there a code that will automatically clear the chat? Also the code for posting the topics. Can it pull the topic from a separate file like a word document. Is any of this possible?

Answer (score 0):

- Use the [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) package to help with the defined intervals or specific time.
- As for pulling the topic from a file, please take a look at Node's native [fs module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).